# Why are code-first tables not being created using Entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

Yet another in the saga of the ASP MVC [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAtVv1Q7ufM) I'm working through. Everything was going along pretty nicely, except, I noticed that two of the three tables being created had no data in them. Unable to figure out why, I got serious and deleted the database thinking I would let it be created again from scratch. Well, now the database is created, but has no tables in it. AND, data that would be in a table is still getting passed to the view. I'm very confused.

SchoolContext.cs

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
....
....
```

SchoolInitializer.cs

```
public class SchoolInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
    {
        var students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student{FirstName = "James", LastName = "Dean", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015")},
            new Student{FirstName = "Linda", LastName = "Thames", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015")}
        };

        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            context.Students.Add(student);  
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

...And a Courses table and an Enrollment table...
```

XyzController.cs

```
public class XyzController : Controller
{
    private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();
    // GET: Xyz
    public ActionResult Abc()
    {
        var students = db.Students.ToList();
```

[image: Student data is passed to view]

[image: But no tables in the DB]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging, especially the part at the bottom on tags in titles.

Comment: Interesting. I would rather have the stuff in the title than the tags, since that is what will pop out at people. "Why are tables not being created?" is such a general question and could apply to any context from pure SQL to PHP to Python.

Comment: The tags feature is so rich on [so] that it's much better to use the tags. And that leaves more room for a sensible title that doesn't need to have tags forced into it. The way I think of it is, leave "data" in the title, but "metadata" in the tags. Keep in mind that many people use tags to filter out questions they're not interested in, or to highlight questions that they _are_ interested in. You've already narrowed down your audience by properly using tags.

Comment: I would read a completely wide open title like you edited mine to and think "The question the OP is asking is probably as poorly defined as the title. I think I'll skip it." Regardless of the philosophical merits of using tags, I'm pretty sure a lot of users operate the same way as I do.

Comment: Feel free to change your title to something without tags that helps you out. Maybe something like "Why isn't my database migration setup creating tables?" Note that your original title was still vague and broad, as there are so many ways for tables (you didn't say database tables) to be created in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok, I see the value in that. I wish I knew more about what I was actually doing here -- it would help me frame a better question. From where I stand, all I know is that I'm following instructions to create tables using a code-first process in ASP.NET MVC 5 in Visual Studio. Hopefully I'll learn more about what I'm actually doing as the tutorial goes on...

Comment: Or, you could go learn about Entity Framework Code-First outside of the tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your Database Initializer setup correctly?
You will need something like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BlogContext>());
```

You should put this line in the Application_Start() method in Global.asax
If yes, you can recycle your app pool to make this code to run again.

Comment: As you can see, I've got the data  seeding just exactly as you have. Where do I set the database initializer?

Comment: @abalter you can put it in your global.asax in Application_Start method

Comment: Aha. I'm using MVC 5. There are no .asax files.

Comment: Wait. I found global.asax. I tried renaming the context to `StudentContext2` everywhere to see if I can jump start it. Still debugging...